# Problemas con Deploy en Nuxt3

Tags: deployment, nuxt, error500

Termine una app simple una landing page y cuando hago el deploy arroja un error (500 Cannot access 'g' before initialization) revisando el código veo que no puede cargar las imágenes en local he revisado por toda la web pero no doy con una solución dejo muestra en imágenes del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se ve claramente no la carga, pero revisando la carpeta donde las almacena, veo que efectivamente la imagen si esta allí, pero veo que no se si es por la ruta que no carga o deba hacer una configuración en el nuxt.config.ts para que lea la ruta correctamente, tengo que acotar que en desarrollo funciona correctamente, no tuve problemas de ruta para ver las imágenes.